# Regular Exprssion in JMeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have the following in my response body:

```
aBB1="N|1234A1234|blahblahblah"
```

I want to take only `1234A1234` using Regular Expression Extractor in `jmeter`.

Would you kindly provide me a suitable regex, please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks. But, I have a problem here. That blahblahblah may be different sentence each time. So, will that work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ...

```
aBB1="N|(.+?)|blahblahblah"
```

This will extract **1234A1234**

You can skip blahblahblah as well, but you need to make sure this **aBB1="N|.....|** pattern should never change, this will extract value between pipes(||) which is **1234A1234** in this case

```
aBB1="N|(.+?)|
```

See [Jmeter Reference Here](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)

Comment: I am getting only "A" here. What template should I use? I am using $1$ now

Comment: What template should I use here. Currently using $1$ and getting only A here from 1234A1234

Comment: @ShankarS, `aBB1="N|(.+?)|` will surely extract `1234A1234` from `aBB1="N|1234A1234|`, yes you are using right template `$1$`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aBB1="N\|([0-9A-Z]*)\|blahblahblah"`

It extracts combination of digits from 0-9 and alpabets from A-Z

You can use [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) to test your regular expressions

More info :

[JMeter Extraction using regular expressions](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/jmeter-extract-and-re-use-as-variable/)